# Use of binary semaphore in the code

Tags: operating-system, semaphore, binary-semaphore

A certain computation generates two arrays `a` and `b` such that
`a[i]=f(i) for 0 ≤ i < n and b[i] = g(a[i]) for 0 ≤ i < n`. Suppose this computation is decomposed into two concurrent processes `X` and `Y` such that `X` computes the array `a` and `Y` computes the array `b`. The processes employ two binary semaphores `R` and `S`, both initialized to zero. The array `a` is shared by the two processes. The structures of the processes are shown below.

```
Process X:                         
private i;                         
for (i=0; i < n; i++) {            
    a[i] = f(i);                       
    ExitX(R, S);                       
 }                                 

Process Y:
private i;
for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
    EntryY(R, S);
    b[i]=g(a[i]);
}
```

Which one of the following represents the CORRECT implementations of `ExitX` and `EntryY`?

(A)

```
ExitX(R, S) {
    P(R);
    V(S);
}

EntryY (R, S) {
    P(S);
    V(R);
}
```

(B)

```
ExitX(R, S) {
    V(R);
    V(S);
}

EntryY(R, S) {
    P(R);
    P(S);
}
```

(C)

```
ExitX(R, S) {
    P(S);
    V(R);
}

EntryY(R, S) {
    V(S);
    P(R);
}
```

(D)

```
ExitX(R, S) {
    V(R);
    P(S);
}
EntryY(R, S) {
    V(S);
    P(R);
}
```

*I believe the answer should be (B)* because critical section in process `Y` should not be executed until critical section in `X` is executed (`a[i]` is filled first, which will have to be used for `b[i]`), so after `X` is executed then according to option (B) at the entry of critical section in `Y` we will find `R=1`, `S=1` ,so now critical section in `Y` can be executed.

**Question**: The correct answer is (C), where am I wrong ?

Comment: B collapses two locks so it can't be correct. the point here is to coordinate two loops. let me write it up.

Answer (score 2):

'B' would work if they were not binary semaphores: in that case X could create an element, increase a single semaphore, and Y could wait on that semaphore and using those items. The semaphore could count how many items are available for processing. And one semaphore would be enough for this.

However you have binary semaphores. So you can only count up to one, e.g. X can create an element, signal the semaphore, but then in can not continue creating elements, since it can not raise that semaphore value to "2" (or more). So it has to wait for that single element to be recognized by Y. And that waiting introduces the second semaphore, signalling X when the current element is getting processed. It is important to remember, that P waits for the semaphore to increase if necessary (and V does the increase), so X could not wait for a single semaphore to go back to 0, as there is no such operation.

And that is what 'C' is doing, S is practically a 'data ready' signal and R is 'acknowledgement'. X says, it is ready, then waits for acknowledgement. While Y waits for ready and sends the acknowledgement.

Answer (score 2):

First off, consider why we even need two semaphores here. The reason is we have two things here to coordinate,

1. Y loop can't start `i` before X loop finishes `i`
2. X loop cannot start `i+1` before Y finishes `i`.

So there are two semaphores, each of them manage one point above.

The semaphore achieves 1 will need to call `P` from `ExitX`. And `EntryY` needs to call `V`. so B is gone here already. To achieve 2, we need `V` in `ExitX` and `P` in `EntryY`.

So look at A, nobody increases anything, so it's a deadlock.

C does the job.

D is not quite right, because both `X` and `Y` might hit `V` twice before any `P` of that semaphore being called.

Comment: here functions ExitX and EntryY are being considered atomic,right ?

Comment: @chunky no it's not. only `P` and `V` are atomic.

Comment: here the moment `ExitX`  is executed, updated values of semaphores are `S=0 , R=1`, so now according to `EntryY` in `option (C)` control reaches and executes, `b[i]=g(a[i])`  in `process Y`, now updated semaphore values are `S=1 , R=0` and this ensures another run of `a[i] = f(i)` in `process X`, right?

Comment: @chun no. ExitX will block because S is initially 0. So EntryY needs to go first.

Comment: but similarly `R` is also `0` initially then how  `EntryY` can go first?

Comment: @chun because after `EntryY` increases `S`, it will need to wait for `ExitX` increases `R`, which has just been released by `S`.